# Hide menu bars on Windows apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-computer

I'm newly returned to windows after working with a mac for years. One of the biggest frustrations I'm facing is the menu bars up the top of apps. 
It has a whole row just for the name and another row for the menu apps.
Is there any way to auto hide the menu bar from applications so that it takes up less room on my monitor.

On a Mac this would be achieved by making the app go full-screen, is there anything similar on Windows?

[image: Menu Bars]

Comment: The application itself would have to support hiding context menu in question.  If the application does not then it cannot be hidden.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Do you want this for AE only, or all and any programs?

Comment: It would be great to be able to do this with AE specifically. The question was more aimed at figuring out how to doing this across all apps, but I'd be happy to learn how to do it in AE.